# How to prove that: $|f(x+h)-f(x)| \leq 2|f(x)|$ for continuous $f$ and sufficiently small $h$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

If I have a continuous function $f$, how can I prove that $$|f(x+h)-f(x)| \leq 2|f(x)| $$ for all sufficiently small $h$?

for example  if I suppose that $f$ is not continous. I know only that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ how can I prove the inequality?

thanks :)

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $h$ might need to depend on $x.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of $f$ being continuous at $x$:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall h: |h| < \delta \implies |f(x+h)-f(x)| < \epsilon$$

The desired inequality follows from applying this to $\epsilon = 2|f(x)|$. Note that we had to assume $f(x) \ne 0$ (since $\epsilon > 0$ is required).

Comment: can you detailed please! thanks :)

Comment: @Iuli How's that for you?

Comment: for example  if I suppose that $f$ is not continous. I know only that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ how can I prove the inequality? Thanks :)

Comment: @Iuli Such constitutes an altogether new question. Should it not have been asked and answered yet (please search!), just post it as one. You can link it to this question if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Continuity at $x$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. Assuming $f(x)\neq 0$, for your question take $\epsilon=2f(x)$...

If it helps you think about it, $x$ is some fixed number. It is not varying and the $\delta$ you get very much depends on $x$.